# Can a gentile read the Torah

Tags: gentiles, torah-study

Can a gentile read the torah? I've heard numerous people say that studying the torah is forbidden to a gentile , under the penalty of death. My question is, what exactly does the word "study" entail? I've seen some people say it refers to any reading of the Torah other than the seven laws of Noah, and others say its fine as long as you don't read the Oral Torah or commentary, and still others say even that's fine as long as the gentile in question doesn't complete absorb themselves in study. So, which is it? Could I read the written Torah, in an English translation and without commentary? Thanks. Also, does the term "written Torah" refer only to the five books of Moses, or to the entire Tanak. Thanks.

Comment: See this answer from Shmuel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/129920/is-a-gentile-who-studies-the-torah-liable-to-death-or-highest-respect?rq=1. Note: times are a'changing. Once upon a time, we lost interest in teaching the gentiles Torah because they kept killing us, but now the Lubavitcher Rebbe says the world is ready again and exhorted us to go and teach it again. I strongly recommend learning it from a Jew, rather than by yourself. Even Jews are not supposed to _just_ learn by themselves. The tradition is vital.

Comment: Also, the Written Torah is the whole of Tanach